# CSS - How to align the text with image without stretching it

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am looking for solution of how can I align text with image and the image remains unstretched.

I am using the following code which in reactjs

```
return (
    <div className="App">
      <div style={{ marginTop: 10 }}>
        <div className="import-option">
          <img
            src={`https://uploads.codesandbox.io/uploads/user/7b703edc-140c-4f14-aa28-17e618788f1e/9zzd-download.png`}
          /><span className="import-option-button"> User Import(CSV)</span>
        </div>
        <div className="import-option">
          <img
            src={`https://uploads.codesandbox.io/uploads/user/7b703edc-140c-4f14-aa28-17e618788f1e/9zzd-download.png`}
          /><span className="import-option-button"> User Import(Export)</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

and following css

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.import-option-button {
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #4da1ff;
}

.import-option-button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.import-option {
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Here is the [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/zlzpj62r4x) which contains the code.

This is what I want to achieve

[image]

Problems in the demo are

1. Image is stretched
2. It is not aligned to left like in the screenshot

How to solve above problems.

Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: A user of 10K rep should surely know by now: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.**

Comment: @Pete Thanks for noticing, I did include demo which contains the whole code and explained properly, I would appreciate if you could edit the way it should be?

Comment: read the bit in bold in my comment - this is meant to be a repository of information for future visitors who may have similar problems and if your link rots then this question will be of no use at all as no one will know what you problem is.  As your problem seems to be with css only, you do not need all the react stuff - just enough css and html to replicate your problem (which you can do using a snippet in your question) - see how to create a [mcve]

Comment: Yes I will add code, I missed it since I was doing it in react though it is related to HTML and CSS purely, sometimes you are not in such frame of mind to all the stuffs properly. Thanks.

Comment: Please don't downvote the question for another reason, there is nothing wrong in it. Thanks. If you find problem please suggest edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment you have .App as text-align: center. this means that all your text in the code will be centre aligned unless you state otherwise in the child divs.

```
    .import-option {
      padding-bottom: 5px;
      text-align: left!important;
      margin-left: 350px;
    }
```

Here is your [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/3ylrw11kvq) updated

Comment: Thanks. Your solution works with the addition of `.import-option img { vertical-align: bottom; }` code from solution by @Abdul Basit.

Answer (score 1):

```
Add CSS for image: 

  **.import-option img { vertical-align: bottom; }**
```

Answer (score 0):

I have checked and modified your code please use the following css in addition

```
.import-option {
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  clear: both;
}
.import-option img{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 4px 0 0;

}
.import-option span{
  float: left;
  padding: 7px 0;
}
```

Updated Code Demo : https://codesandbox.io/s/y05167v0lv

Comment: Thanks for the solution.. But you missed one thing, image is still squeezed, if you look into the original [image](https://uploads.codesandbox.io/uploads/user/7b703edc-140c-4f14-aa28-17e618788f1e/9zzd-download.png) it is different.

Comment: Then you can remove the width and height mentioned in css

.import-option img{

  float: left;
  margin: 0 4px 0 0;

}

Answer (score 0):

Just simply apply flex property to the `.import-option`

```
.import-option {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
}
```